# Copy row to another sheet on Google Sheets based on criteria and cell value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am attempting to copy some row values from Sheet1 to Sheet2 based on a criteria and a cell value where some rows are only copied when [Qualification] = 'Qualified' and, if [No of positions] = 1 then the values are copied once, if [No of positions] = 2 then the values are copied twice.

Below is an example.

**Sheet1**

| Lead Type | Lead ID | Company Name | Employment Type | No of positions | Qualification |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| External | B21 | KidRed Co. | Full Time | 1 | Not Qualified |
| Africa | B24 | Freddie Co. | Part Time | 2 | Qualified |
| Base | B35 | Akila Co. | Full Time | 1 | Qualified |
| External | B40 | SeeQue Co. | Part Time | 1 | Not Qualified |

**Sheet2**

| Lead ID | Company Name | Qualification |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B24 | Freddie Co. | Qualified |
| B24 | Freddie Co. | Qualified |
| B35 | Akila Co. | Qualified |

I am open to both an App Script solution or a formula. What I have managed to do so far is use the following query `=query('Sheet1'!A:F, "select B,C,F where F = 'Qualified'", 0)` on cell B2 in Sheet2. It only copies the values once and doesn't take into account the cell value.

P.S I am very new to using Google Sheets. Please assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Google Apps Script is used, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet and save the script. When you use this script, please put a custom function like `=SAMPLE(A2:F)` to a cell. By this, the result is obtained.

```js
const SAMPLE = v => v.flatMap(([, b, c, , e, f]) => e > 0 ? [...Array(e)].fill([b, c, f]) : []);
```

- When you change the retrieved values, please modify `[, b, c, , e, f]` and `[b, c, f]`.

#### Testing:

When this script is run to your sample input values, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Note:

- If you want to retrieve the rows including `"Qualified"` in the column "F", you can also use the following sample script.

  ```
    const SAMPLE = v => v.flatMap(([, b, c, , e, f]) => e > 0 && f == "Qualified" ? [...Array(e)].fill([b, c, f]) : []);
  ```

  - In this case, the following result is obtained.

    [image]

#### References:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)
- [flatMap()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

### Added:

About your following question,

> How would you do this when copying from one sheet to another?

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please set `srcSheetName` and `dstSheetName` and run the script.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const srcSheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the source sheet name.
  const dstSheetName = "Sheet2"; // Please set the destination sheet name.

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const [srcSheet, dstSheet] = [srcSheetName, dstSheetName].map(s => ss.getSheetByName(s));
  const [, ...v] = srcSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  const values = v.flatMap(([, b, c, , e, f]) => e > 0 && f == "Qualified" ? [...Array(e)].fill([b, c, f]) : [])
  dstSheet.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
  // Or, dstSheet.getRange(dstSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

Comment: How would you do this when copying from one sheet to another?

Comment: @Sharon Kerubo Thank you for replying. About your question of `How would you do this when copying from one sheet to another?`, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your additional question, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you so much @Tanaike. Both your solutions work perfectly and the explanation is precise. Another way to use your first script and copy from Sheet1 to Sheet2 is to write the custom function in a cell in Sheet2 like this =SAMPLE('Sheet1'!A:F)

Comment: @Sharon Kerubo Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: hello, id like to follow up on this request. Currently if i delete one record from the source sheet name, only the columns copied are deleted on the destination sheet name. This means that there is a mismatch if i have data in the columns after. I would like to be able to edit/delete the entire row if i am to change/delete the row from the source sheet.

Comment: @Sharon Kerubo I would like to support you. But the issue of your comment is new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: yes, I can post it as a new question. Thank you for your guidance.

Comment: Hello @Tanaike, When i try run the Sample Script above it gives me this error. 'Exception: You do not have permission to call setValues' . Could you please assist with this?

Comment: @Sharon Kerubo About `When i try run the Sample Script above it gives me this error. 'Exception: You do not have permission to call setValues' . Could you please assist with this?`, I would like to support you. But your comment is new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: @Sharon Kerubo By the way, when you used `myFunction()` as a custom function, such an error occurs. In this case, please run the script with the script editor instead of the custom function. Please be careful about this.